# Image fade out on landing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have a full screen image appear when a user visits a site, then after a delay it fades out and reveals the website.  I know this can probably be done through jQuery.  Does anyone know of a good resource or code snippet for this?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean actual full screen, as in the whole monitor/screen and not just the browser window? If it's the whole entire screen, I doubt that's possible since you will be constrained by the resolution of the browser window. Unless the user is viewing the browser in full screen mode, I don't think this can be done.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut has a good example.  Just add an image to your page, and call the fadeout using window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your image is in div TheIntro and the site is wrapped in a div called TheMainDiv, then you could use jquery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#TheIntro').animate({opacity: 0.01}, 500, function () {

        $(this).hide();
        $('#TheMainDiv').fadeIn(500);             

    });   
});
```

I don't think you need a plugin for that effect. The first value of 500 is the time it takes for the intro image to fade out and the second value is for the time it takes for the site to fade in.

Comment: Could I do something along the lines of putting the image outside of the body tag, then show the body? I don't have a wrapper or container.

Comment: No, I think that by definition you can't put things outside the body tag. In your case, the body would need to be hidden (which is possible BTW) while you're showing an image; but where in the DOM would that image be?

Comment: I suppose I could wrap everything in an empty div then put an div with  an image above that?

Comment: That worked pretty damn well @frenchie thank you.  Just need to work on tweaking the fadeIn.  It's not fading in how I expect, I dunno if its the duration or my markup causing it.

Comment: You can also do something like this if you don't want to change your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/XsqPF/

Comment: @eithed this looks great also, but won't work with how I have the background set up for full screen.  I'm using background instead of background-image with prefixes for browsers.  Any ideas?  I changed the jQuery around to accommodate just background but it didn't fade out.

Comment: @Ben - will work with background as well: http://jsfiddle.net/XsqPF/1/

as for centered, full screen image: http://jsfiddle.net/XsqPF/2/

Of course - if you want the image to be adaptive, you'll have to go with frenchie method, as even with css3 option of adaptive background, it produces weird results: http://jsfiddle.net/XsqPF/3/

Comment: @Ben: just got back online. Glad you worked it out and happy coding!